# Ternary IF-check not working properly

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm trying to print out a specific image based on a user's cookie.

The cookie can have either of the 2 values: `en` or `es`. First I'd like to check if that cookie exists in the first place. If it does, then print out its value. Else, it should print out `en`.

It's a language cookie. `en = english`, `es = spanish`.
And I have two flags, one english flag and one spanish flag, in `/img/flags/` folder, and they have the names `en.gif` and `es.gif`

Here is my code:

`<img src="/img/flags/<?php (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) ? $_COOKIE['lang'] : 'en') ?>.gif">`

Right now it just prints out an empty image (no file name) regardless if I have a cookie set or not: `/img/flags/.gif`

What am I doing wrong?

I'd rather use a ternary because it looks nicer. If I do a regular IF-check it works fine:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
  echo $_COOKIE['lang'];
} else {
  echo 'en';
}
```

Comment: Why downvotes? Elaborate.

Comment: The question of comments + downvotes has been discussed ad nauseum on Meta. Many folks just choose to DV and move on. Many offer advice. Many try to light the path for newbies. Regardless, you may not be able to get a response from those who have DV'd your question as they have likely moved on.

Answer (score 1):

You still have to echo the ternary results:

```
<img src="/img/flags/<?php echo (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) ? $_COOKIE['lang'] : 'en') ?>.gif">
```